# Why am I getting a "TypeError" in an if statement for a list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm working on a little cypher project as a way to learn list comprehension.  I've written a for loop that does what I want (the commented out section) and I've started to write a list comprehension `encMessage = [alph[alph.index(i) + keyShift] for i in list(message)]` that I also commented out.

The list comprehension with the additional if statement, however, causes: `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects`.

Why is there a type error for the "if" portion but not the expression?

```
import string
alph = string.ascii_lowercase


def encM (message, keyShift):

    # for i in list(message):
    #     tempNum = alph.index(i) + keyShift
    #     if tempNum > 26:
    #         tempNum = tempNum - 26
    #     tempNum = alph[alph.index(i)]
    #     print(tempNum)

    # encMessage = [alph[alph.index(i) + keyShift] for i in list(message)]
    encMessage = [alph[alph.index(i) + keyShift] for i in list(message) if (alph[alph.index(i)] + keyShift > 26)]
    #string1 = ''.join([str(item) for item in encMessage])

print(encMessage)

encM("test", 3)
```

Comment: Double check your placement of square brackets.

Comment: Your code has the expression `alph[alph.index(i)] + keyShift`.  The first thing is a `str`, the second thing is an `int`.

Comment: Answer given by @Felix K Jose looks right but the elephant in the room is you are not returning `encMessage` and you are printing the answer before calling the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was `alph[alph.index(i)] + keyShift` if you change that to `alph.index(i)] + keyShift` it will work, since latter gets index value instead of the str value at the index.

Following solves the exception:

```
encMessage = [alph[alph.index(i) + keyShift] for i in list(message) if (alph.index(i) + keyShift > 26)]
```

But the `encMessage` is empty, then I changed the above code as follows and that seems giving proper shifting:

```
encMessage = [alph[alph.index(i) + keyShift] for i in list(message) if (alph.index(i) + keyShift < 26)]
```

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: It did help. Thank you.  I still need to figure out how to put the rest of the if statement in the list comprehension.

Comment: Finally figured out what I wanted: `encodedList = [alph[alph.index(i) + shiftKey - 26] if alph.index(i) + shiftKey > 26 else alph[alph.index(i) + shiftKey] for i in list(message)]`